# Partially Protecting a Workbook (and allowing for Macros to input into protected cells)

Tags: excel, vba, protected

I have a workbook with multiple tabs. All tabs are protected. Some are fully protected while others are partially protected (that is, column and row size can be adjusted). There is one page of inputs. When the macro button is pressed, all the other tabs are populated. In order to allow the tabs to be populated by a macro even where the cells are locked I have used the following code on Workbook Opening:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim wSheet As Worksheet
    For Each wSheet In Worksheets
        wSheet.Protect Password:="Secret", _
        UserInterFaceOnly:=True
Next wSheet
End Sub
```

However, this resets all the tabs to be fully protected (whereas some only need to be partially protected).

Is there a way around this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I think you will need to specify the setting for each sheet (or each group of sheets with the same type of protection)

Answer (score 0):

The  Sheet.Protect seems to have a parameter for

```
AllowFormattingColumns  Optional    Variant
```

True allows the user to format any column on a protected worksheet. The default value is False .

Have you tried this?